# How to display text in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn when the databound value is null

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have a databound DataGridView with a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. If the combobox value is null I want to display a text. I do not want to add a null item to the databound list as I need to display different text in each datagridview line.
How would I achieve this using the default datagridview control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CellFormatting event to alter any displayed value:

```
//attach in code or via designer:
dataGridView1.CellFormatting += new DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellFormatting);


    //example implementation:
    void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {  
        if (e.ColumnIndex == Column1.Index && e.Value==null)//where Column1 is your combobox column
        {
            e.Value = "Empty";
            e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I change the value to something that is not in the databound list then I get an error.

Comment: Any other ideas? The problem is that the DataGridViewComboBoxCell has no text property. The value is databound, so there's no way to assign a text to it.

Comment: Could you try if it works if e.FormattingApplied = true; is set? (also edited the original post to add it)

Comment: Aaaaaaaahhhh, my bad. I was trying to assign a value directly to the cell and not via the EventArgs. Doing exactly what you wrote works like a charm! Thanks a lot.